# Getting index of an element in array containing another element

Tags: python, arrays

So lets say I have this array :

```
array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

and I want to get the index of the inner array containing the 5 for example. So in this case the returned index I want is 1.

I did try `ind = array.index(5)` but I'm quite aware why this didnt work since the value in the brackets have to match the element in the array exactly. Another way I did this is

```
counter = 0
for each in array:
  if 5 in each: break
  else: counter = counter + 1
```

and this worked well for what I want but I wanted to check if there is an easier and cleaner way to do this. Thanks

Comment: That seems the most efficient/readable way to me.

Comment: Readability is very subjective here:  a lot of programmers would argue that  itertools are more clear than mishmash of cycles with episodic breaks in them.  Efficiency: rather no. Itertools

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a slightly better pythonic approach using `next(..)`. Remember that if 5 doesn't exist in any of the sub-arrays, this will throw a `StopIteration`. You might want to handle that.

```
>>> your_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> next(i for i, x in enumerate(your_list) if 5 in x)
1
```

Comment: how would this return the index though?

Comment: @L.D Yes, that was my mistake. I just fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Better avoid `break`s. Here is a better way:

```
for ind, inner_arr in enumerate(array):
    if 5 in inner_arr:
        return ind
```

Answer (score 2):

one liner solution

```
#a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[i for i, j in enumerate(a)  if 5 in j][0]
```

Comment: Using `next(..)` on a generator expression might give you an equivalent of a short-circuit as in my answer without having to construct an entire list

Comment: yeah, i've totally forgotten it -))

Answer (score 1):

What you have seems the way to go, but there are some improvements possible:

```
def find(item, array):
    counter = 0
    for each in array:
        if item in each:
            return counter
        counter = counter + 1
    return None
```

But even the counter can be automated:

**Update:** actually don't need return None - this is the default of all functions

```
def find(item, array):
    for idx, each in enumerate(array):
        if item in each:
            return idx
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use `index` method, here is a possible approach:

```
[x.index(5) for x in array if 5 in x]
```

Comment: do not forget to get zeroth item -))

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the use of `enumerate()`, I'd go with the following code:

```
for elem in array:
     for i in elem:
             if 5 in elem: print array.index(elem)
             break
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a `counter` variable really. I would go for:

```
for inner_array in array:
  if inner_array.index(5) > -1:
    return array.index(inner_array);
return None;
```

Comment: you may want to return None, instead of -1; as -1 is also a valid index. :)

Comment: what if 5 was in index 0 of the inner array?

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
counter = 0

for item in array:
    for n in item:
        if n == 5:
            counter += 1
    print counter
```

Probably more efficient ways to do it, but this works for me

Comment: I think you placed counter += 1 in the wrong for loop. If the array was array=[[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[4,5,6]] .. the index your code gives is still 1

Answer (score 0):

I see functional examples, so I'm a bit late:

```
[(id,inner.index(5)) for id,inner 
 in enumerate(arr) 
 if 5 in inner]
```